# Angular Newbie - Unable to use $scope variable inside a controller function

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular.js controller code.

```
angular.module("myapp", [])
   .controller("JiraReportController", function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.Epics = {};
        $scope.Epics.sprint = "15S04";

        $scope.Epics.getDefectInfo = function(item, event) {
            console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" . $scope.Epics.sprint);
            $http.get("getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" . $scope.Epics.sprint)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.Epics = data;
            })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("AJAX failed!" + config.url);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When I access the function , I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Epics' of undefined
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error. Please help this Angular Newbie.

Comment: What line is it erroring out on? There are 5 different places that `$scope.Epics` is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your log:

```
console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" . $scope.Epics.sprint);
```

should be

```
console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" + $scope.Epics.sprint);
```

(replace the `.` by a `+`, same error in the `$http` call)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you concatenate strings with a `+`, not `.`

Try

```
console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" + $scope.Epics.sprint);
```

and

```
$http.get("getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" + $scope.Epics.sprint)
```

Answer (score 0):

First check, as told above, you can write

```
console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" . $scope.Epics.sprint);
```

as

```
console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=", $scope.Epics.sprint);
```

or

```
console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint="+$scope.Epics.sprint);
```

I prefer the first style of passing arguments by separating them with comma. Because that follows the signature of console.log as below

```
console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN);
console.log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN);
```

For line no 9 too, change it to:

`$http.get("getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" + $scope.Epics.sprint)`

and let us know what exact error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Addition operator instead of .

console.log("Calling getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" + $scope.Epics.sprint);

AND

$http.get("getDefectsForEpics.php?sprint=" + $scope.Epics.sprint